# Ajuda com Erro PHP e SQL

Tags: php, sql, xampp

Galera, estou fazendo um projeto de uma locadora, mas os dados não estão sendo enviados, esse é o código:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "locadora";
$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>RECEBIDO</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        if($_POST["img_ok"]) {
            $tempname = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
            $name = uniqid();
            $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["img"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Pega extensão de arquivo e converte em caracteres minúsculos.

            $url_exibir = "imagem/".$name.".".$extension; // Caminho para exibição da imagem.      

            $url = "imagem/"; // Pasta onde será armazenada a imagem.
            if(!file_exists($url)) { // Verifica se a pasta já existe.
                mkdir($url, 0777, TRUE); // Cria a pasta.
                chmod($url, 0777); // Seta a pasta como modo de escrita.
            }

            move_uploaded_file($tempname, $url."/".$name.".".$extension); // Move arquivo para a pasta em questão.

            $id=0;
            $nome_filme = $_POST['nome_filme'];
            $nome_autor = $_POST['nome_autor'];
            $duração = $_POST['duração'];
            $dd = $_POST['dd'];
            $mm = $_POST['mm'];
            $aaaa = $_POST['aaaa'];
            $data_lançamento=$dd;
            $capa = $name;
            $extenção = $extension;

            $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'locadora');

            $query = "INSERT INTO filmes (id, nome_filme, nome_autor, duração, data_lançamento, capa, extenção) VALUES ('{$id}','{$nome_filme}','{$nome_autor}','{$duração}','{$data_lançamento}', '{$capa}', '{$extenção}')";
            mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

            mysqli_close($conexao);
        }




    ?>

<!-- Exibir imagem de upload -->
<img alt="" title="" src="<?php echo $url_exibir; ?>">
<br />
<a href="index.php">Voltar</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Vocês podem me ajudar?

Comment: Dados é aquele de 6 faces? o que não é enviado os campos do form ou o arquivo?

Comment: No caso dados, os dados do filme! O arquivo esta sendo enviado mas as informações do filme não :(

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o form ou se quiser testar, pode fazer, `print_r($_POST` ou `print_r($_GET)` no arquivo que recebe os dados.

Comment: Tem certeza que sua query sql está correta? Se sua tabela tiver mesmo os nomes das colunas com `ç` e `~` coloque-os da seguinte forma  ```(`id`, `nome_filme`, `nome_autor`, `duração`, `data_lançamento`, `capa`, `extenção`)```